# Kill process over network with batch file

Tags: database, batch-file, transfer, corrupt

The 1st question is about batch commands, the 2nd is about a database corruption if you care to read.

1. Does anyone know the batch command to kill a process (.exe) over the network ie from a server to a front-office PC.

I have an application which runs nightly to create a cut-down (~1Mb) version of a Membership database (~10Mb) on a backoffice PC and then transfers it to a number of Tills, replacing the one that is there.

The files are advantage databases (.ADT .ADM .ADI) and the aim is to create a smaller file for reference by our Point of Sale software.

At 2 of our clients sites, at random intervals these files will be corrupted and our software cannot from them.

There is no activity going on with these files at the time of creation & transfering and the Point of Sale software (should) be turned off on all computers.

1. Does anyone have any suggestion as to why this may happen? My only idea is to really make sure the software is killed over network before copying the file across.

Many thanks in advance,
ian

Answer (score 2):

You need to download `pskill` from SysInternals.  This allows you to kill processes on remote machines:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683

If you're reading a file that's being written to by another process, then you may end up with an inconsistent view of that file (i.e. corruption).

Comment: Thanks I'll check out pskill. Any 3rd party software will have to be installed on the clients server so I was hoping there was a command.

e.g. launching a batch on the remote computer with the taskkill /IM command.

Yeah my only answer is that the software is open and thus the file is active. Though it's a late night daily routine so no reading/writing to the file will be happening at the exact time.

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to install `pskill` on the remote machine - as long as you're an admin, it'll copy itself over when you invoke it.

Comment: It seems I have to put pskill in the current directory, which is fine. I'll implement the kill and report back if it solves the problem.
Many thanks Steve

Comment: If you put it in a folder that is within your `PATH`, you should be fine running it from anywhere.